# how to retrieve data using Dynamodb parallel scans using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, multithreading, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on importing a dynamo table to S3 using nodejs. I have everything working fine but the entire copy is pretty slow as I have millions of records and the sequential scan is limited to 1MB, so I am looking in doing a parallel scan for dynamo dB using node.

But to do that, I need to create multiple threads and assign the parallel work to those threads in node. I would like to know if there is a recommended way of doing that, or do you suggest using Data Pipeline for importing data? How do you think I should go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **in-build parallel scan** feature available in the `Scan API`. The entire will be divided into multiple segments and scan will be performed on the individual segments.

[Parallel scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan)

```
Segment: 0,
TotalSegments: 5
```

> Segment: For a parallel Scan request, Segment identifies an individual
>   segment to be scanned by an application worker.
>
> Segment IDs are zero-based, so the first segment is always 0. For
>   example, if you want to use four application threads to scan a table
>   or an index, then the first thread specifies a Segment value of 0, the
>   second thread specifies 1, and so on.
>
> The value for Segment must be greater than or equal to 0, and less
>   than the value provided for TotalSegments.
>
> If you provide Segment, you must also provide TotalSegments.
>
> TotalSegments:- For a parallel Scan request, TotalSegments represents
>   the total number of segments into which the Scan operation will be
>   divided. The value of TotalSegments corresponds to the number of
>   application workers that will perform the parallel scan. For example,
>   if you want to use four application threads to scan a table or an
>   index, specify a TotalSegments value of 4.